# What the differences are between Google Tag Manager and Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-tag-manager

While looking to process a few variables from a form, and send that data to a Google Drive Spreadsheet, I found that Google Apps Script, fits better for my purpose, it just catchs all the data in a regular html form, and sends that data to my Google Drive Spreadsheet, without depending on a special type of google form, and without matching var names, vith values.

Am I missing something?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Tag Manager gives you the power to create and update tags for your website and mobile apps, any time you want, at the speed of your business. You can go through the documentation [here](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/).

You can also refer to this [page](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/google-tag-manager) for more idea on what Tag manager is.

For your requirement of getting the data from a form to a Google Spreadsheet, Google Apps Script fits better.

You can refer to these links for more information of Appscript:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#connecting_to_google_forms

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Hope that helps!